# Lubuntu 20.04 unable to switch window manager

Tags: lubuntu, i3-wm

I am aware that when using ubuntu to switch window managers you have to select it in the 'gear icon' upon startup. This option is not available in Lubuntu.

My window manager is Openbox and I want to change it to i3.

I think that the answer is to create a **xsession script**, but I don't know where to create that.

When looking I found the directory /usr/share/xsessions within I found `i3.desktop  i3-with-shmlog.desktop  Lubuntu.desktop  lxqt.desktop  openbox.desktop` If I delete the openbox.desktop file. Wouldn't my system run the i3.desktop file?

Comment: Unrelated, but Lubuntu 20.04 goes end-of-life near the end of April 2023, which is about a month away at the time of this writing. The Lubuntu-specific parts of your system will stop receiving updates after that. You may want to consider upgrading to Lubuntu 22.04 soon. Note that even after Lubuntu 20.04 goes end-of-life, the underlying Ubuntu 20.04 operating system will still be supported until 2025, so you will still get some software updates after that. Just the Lubuntu team will no longer be working on or supporting Lubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

The option to switch between window managers and desktop environments is handled by your display manager. It would look like SDDM is the default display manager for Lubuntu per https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.8/sddm_configuration.html. The directions you reference with the 'gear icon' specifically apply to GDM which is the display manager for Gnome. You should not have to delete any xsession desktop entries in order to use i3. SDDM is incredibly configurable and can look very different depending on the situation but typically has a "Session" drop down selection box that should allow selecting i3 or openbox.

Comment: In Lubuntu, the "Session" dropdown is in the upper-left corner of the screen - it should be possible to select i3 from there. (Just adding that so that people know where to look for the dropdown you mentioned.)